# Find common values between SQL table & list in SQL Query like this

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, mariadb

This is my sample data set...

```
CREATE TABLE blockhashtable (id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,pos int,filehash varchar(35), blockhash varchar(130) );

insert into blockhashtable 
(pos,filehash,blockhash) values 
(1, "random_md51", "randstr1"),
(2, "random_md51", "randstr2"),
(3, "random_md51", "randstr3"),
(1, "random_md52", "randstr2"),
(2, "random_md52", "randstr2"),
(3, "random_md52", "randstr2"),
(4, "random_md52", "randstr1"),
(5, "random_md52", "randstr7"),
(1, "random_md53", "randstr2"),
(2, "random_md53", "randstr1"),
(3, "random_md53", "randstr2"),
(4, "random_md53", "randstr1"),
(1, "random_md54", "randstr1"),
(2, "random_md54", "randstr55");
```

Current SQL Query (Need to be fixed):

```
SELECT filehash
     , GROUP_CONCAT(pos ORDER BY pos) pos
     , (avg(blockhash IN('randstr1','randstr2','randstr3','randstr2','randstr2'))) as ratio
  FROM blockhashtable
 GROUP
    BY filehash
```

Current output (Need to be fixed)

```
filehash    pos        ratio
random_md51 1,2,3      1
random_md52 1,2,3,4,5  0.8
random_md53 1,2,3,4    1
random_md54 1,2        0.5
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b5220/10

Expected output:

```
filehash    pos        ratio
random_md51 1,2,3      1
random_md52 1,2,3,4    0.8
random_md53 1,2,3      0.75
random_md54 1          0.5
```

I am basically trying to find "similar blockhash" between the query list & sql table.

About ratio columns:

If `randomstr1` appear only once in the SQL query, then I want maximum 1 match for `randomstr1` in the SQL db.

In the third output row. `ratio` is 0.75 because `randomstr1` appear only one time in query, even if it appear twice in MySQL table. So in third row, we found 3/4 match. `randomstr2` is matched both times in third row because it appears 2 or more times in SQL query.

About the `pos`. I just want to know the `pos` value of the `matched blocks`.

Comment: As far as i can see 1 is correct there are 4 rows with random_md53 and in ('randstr1','randstr2','randstr3') in your case ('randstr1','randstr2')  I don't understand which if these you want to skip.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the wrong quesy....1 minute

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: Please check my edited SQL query @nbk   There are three `randomstr2`

Comment: I am using MySQL-Wordbench 8.0, I think or MySql 8.0...let me confirm again

Comment: 10.4.2 MariaDB, I think

Comment: I don't care which version in all are 4 random_md53  from  your set

Comment: To get 3 out of 4 one has to be "randstr4"  or "randstr5" something dofferent tha your set

Comment: Hey look. In `ratio` column only third row is different from expected & real output, right?

Comment: i chech it more than once 1, "random_md53", "randstr2"),
(2, "random_md53", "randstr1"),
(3, "random_md53", "randstr2"),
(4, "random_md53", "randstr1"),

Comment: It is because `randomstr1` repeat only once in SQL query, So we only do one match instead of all match....So it is 3/4 match only instead of 4/4

Comment: Let me confirm again, please wait

Comment: Hey, @nbk.....All 4 are from my set....But `randomstr1` only repeat once in my set....So we only match it once...Not twice.

Comment: with that logic also "randstr2  repeats it self and so the value must be 0.5 but for all rows the pos are different. and still  random_md52 is also false .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ROW_NUMBER()` window function you can check if 'randomstr1' exists more than or 'randomstr2' exists more than 3 times so you can ignore them:

```
with 
  row_numbers as (
    select *, 
      row_number() over (partition by filehash, blockhash order by pos) rn
    from blockhashtable 
  ),
  cte as (
    select *, 
    (blockhash = 'randstr1' and rn = 1)
    or 
    (blockhash = 'randstr2' and rn <= 3)
    or 
    (blockhash = 'randstr3') valid
    from row_numbers
  )
select filehash,
  group_concat(case when valid then pos end order by pos) pos,
  avg(valid) as ratio
from cte
group by filehash
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=d13129512755daa3f623af93d9eb18bf).
Results:

```
> filehash    | pos     |  ratio
> :---------- | :------ | -----:
> random_md51 | 1,2,3   | 1.00
> random_md52 | 1,2,3,4 | 0.80
> random_md53 | 1,2,3   | 0.75
> random_md54 | 1       | 0.50
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for sorry. In my original query `randomstr2` repeat 3 times, So I want to match it only maximum three times in the table.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :)